# Prove $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ not injective by Inverse Function Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

I'm proving that a $C^r$ function $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not injective. I've seen various solutions but I want to prove it using techniques related to the Inverse function theorem; because it's a problem from Spivaks "Callculus on Manifolds" text in the chapter on the Inverse function theorem.

I've found a function $g:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ defined as $g(x,y)=\bigg(f(x,y),y\bigg)$, and proven that it's $C^r$.  To prove my main problem, I'm assuming $f$ is injective, and that allows me to apply the inverse function theorem to $g$, in such a way that gives me an open map from an open set in the domain of $g$ to the open image of $g$, such that $g$ has a differentiable inverse $g^{-1}:g(A)\rightarrow A$.

Now I want to prove a contradiction in the injectivity of $f$, by showing that $g^{-1}$ is not defined at certain points, specifically a line, and this contradicts the differentiability of $g^{-1}$.  Consider $f(x,y)=b$ then $g(x,y)=(b,y)$, Now I should be able to find that the line that $g^{-1}$ isn't defined on $\forall (b,z)$, $z\neq y$, since that would imply that   $f(x,z)=b$.

**My Question**
*I don't quite see how $g^{-1}$ being defined on $(b,z)$ implies that $f(x,z)=b$?*
$\phantom{}$

Here is the original problem.  I've seen other solutions suggest to make $g$ satisfy the conditions of $f$ from $2$-$36$, which is why I left it in.
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does it mean for 
$$
g^{-1}(b, z) = (u, v)? 
$$
It means that 
$$
g(u, v) = (b, z).
$$
On the other hand, we know that 
$$
g(u, v) = (f(u, v), v)
$$
so setting these two things equal, we see that 
$$
f(u, v) = b\\
v = z
$$
from which we see that 
$$
f(u, z) = b. 
$$
I'm not sure if this was what was confusing you, but it seemed to be.

Comment: That's exactly the part that I couldn't get.  Thanks!

Comment: Early in my proof I claimed that there must exist a neighbhorood where $D_1f(x,y)\neq 0$ because $D_1f=D_2f=0$ would make the 1-1 condition impossible.  Why exactly does $D_1f=D_2f=0$  $\forall$ points in the domain imply that $f$ couldn't be injective?  It seems obvious that critical points on a continuous map couldn't be injective in any neighborhood around the point, but how do I express this?

Comment: That *sounds* like a moment to apply the mean value theorem (or the FTC) along any line in the domain. But I haven't checked this claim, so you're on your own.

Comment: Ok, Thanks again